# Timer with React

Tags: reactjs

I try to do a timer, in arguments we have the time (in seconds) and the name. It work but now I try to add a new timer when I click the button "Add new", I don't know how to do firstly..

https://jsfiddle.net/q806zeps/3/

Here the fiddle..

I add

`<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add new</button>`

and

```
 handleClick(event){}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> TimerMixin We found out that the primary cause of fatals in apps
>   created with React Native was due to timers firing after a component
>   was unmounted. To solve this recurring issue, we introduced
>   TimerMixin. If you include TimerMixin, then you can replace your calls
>   to setTimeout(fn, 500) with this.setTimeout(fn, 500) (just prepend
>   this.) and everything will be properly cleaned up for you when the
>   component unmounts.

```
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';

var Component = createReactClass({
  mixins: [TimerMixin],
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('I do not leak!');
    }, 500);
  },
});
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers